# Are hazard function being constant and the distribution being memoryless equivalent?

Tags: probability

Are [hazard function](http://planetmath.org/HazardFunction.html) (defined for both continuous and discrete distributions) being constant  and the distribution being [memoryless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness) equivalent?

A memoryless distribution has a constant hazard function.

But if a distribution has a constant hazard function, will it be memoryless?

If I am correct, exponential distribution and geometric distribution are the only two distributions that are memoryless.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. (And, sorry to say this, but I feel the quality of your interactions with the site would be improved by a tiny bit of personal work on your part. For example, did you try to use the techniques displayed in the answers to your other questions to solve this (rather simpler) one?)

Comment: According to my lecture slides, exponential function is the only continuous memoryless distribution.